# Can't understand this question related to arithmetic progression.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

I can't understand one thing in one question of *Arithmetic Progression*. I have to find $21^{st}$ term from the set $\{12,2,-4,-10\}$ and this is where problem start.

**Arithmetic Progression**
*Equation:* $T_n=a+(n-1)d$

$Tn$ = Term
$n$ = Term Number
$a$ = First Number 
$d$ = Difference between two series wise numbers

I need this data to find out mentioned number, like $21^{st}$ number, if I find just $d$ I can just count the numbers to see what number is coming at $21^{st}$ position, **but** in this set of numbers, has unmatched difference and I don't know why, either it is right set or wrong.

Let's take example;
If I want to find $5^{th}$ term from set $\{2,4,6...\}$ then I need all the data listed above and if I find just $d$ from this set, I can figure out $5^{th}$ number without using equation.

Here is example;
$d=b-a$ | ***a** is first term and **b** is second term*
$d=4-2$
$d=2$

so the difference between two *"series wise"* numbers is $2$. Now in very first set *"mentioned above"* is different difference in first two terms and in second two terms.
$\{12,2,-4,-8\}$
so first two terms $\{12,2\}$ has difference of $10$
and next two terms $\{2,-4\}$ has difference of $6$.

## why?

Comment: Apparently, your set is not an arithmetic progression.

Comment: Maybe the problem has a flaw.

Comment: $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$ is same equation as equation mentioned above

Comment: In one part $d = 10$ and in other part $d = 6$. Thus, the set is not an arithmetic progression.

Comment: Then what is it, I got that question from Arithmetic Progression questions.

Comment: I'm guessing the first number is supposed to be an 8?  Then it's an arithmetic progression.

Comment: Nitpicking: when you use set notation (namely brackets {..}) you are trying to convey that the order of the elements is irrelevant and that repetitions are irrelevant too ({1,1}={1}), which is not certainly the case in a sequence of any kind. I suggest you drop the brackets.

Comment: But difference *must* be equal in between all numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put this plainly, your sequence is **not** an arithmetic progression. If you set
$$
\{T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4\}=\{12,2,-4,-10\},
$$
then $T_2-T_1=-10$ and $T_3-T_2=-6$, which is completely inconsistent with an arithmetic progression. You also have $T_4-T_3=-6$, so you can sort of hope that the first $12$ is a typo (instead of an $8$), in which case the sequence goes as
$$T_n=12-6(n-1)$$
and the 21st term is then $T_{21}=-108$, but extrapolating based on four not-very-consistent terms is always a very dicy proposition. You will need to weigh this yourself with respect to the source you got this question from: how they phrase the section, how strongly they imply the progression is arithmetic, and how likely they are to have made a typo.

Comment: Well, it's source was my teacher. I told him about this typo error but he said it is correct. Don't know how.

Comment: So there you have it: you need to ask your teacher. The progression is definitely not arithmetic.